# Error en teclado Ionic 4

Tags: android, ionic, ionic4, teclado

Estoy realizando una app en ionic 4 y en el inicio de sesión despues de digitar la contraseña y dar en el botoón de ingreso el teclado desaparece pero deja un espacio en blanco, es decir la aplicación se reduce casi a la mitad de la pantalla que es lo que ocuparia el teclado.

He intentado cambiar el AndroidManifest.xml con el android:windowSoftInputMode
con cada una de las opciones pero ninguna me funciona.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?
[image: Pantalla con el teclado abierto]

[image: Pantalla despues que se cierra el teclado]

Comment: Agrega una imagen y el layout que estas usando, eso puede ayudar a la comunidad a entender que sucede, saludos.

Comment: Ya agregue dos pantallas, muchas gracias.